# Unable to embed an mp4 video in Shiny R from computer

Tags: r, video, shiny, embed, mp4

The result is a black background where the video should be playing.
The video is in the directory of the getwd() in R.
This is the code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$video(src="videoname.mp4", type = "video/mp4",height ="400px", width="400px",controls="controls")
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser =T)
```

[image]

Comment: All internet resources must be placed inside `www` folder. It doesn't use `getwd()` as root,  but `getwd() + 'www'` as the root. or you need to specify a new root with `addResourcePath`